# Theory of Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) in dtwclust package of the software R

Tags: time-series, clustering

I used to utilize dtwclust for my study and I got a problem.
I have read a few studies and I understand the DTW distance like below picture.

[image]

source: A. Akl, S. Valaee, "Accelerometer-based gesture recognition via dynamic-time warping, affinity propagation, & compressive sensing," IEEE International Conference on Acoustics Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), pp.2270-2273, 2010.

and I read then "Comparing Time-Series Clustering Algorithms in R
Using the dtwclust Package". The notation for DTW is different.

[image]

source: Alexis Sard´a-Espinosa, Comparing Time-Series Clustering Algorithms in R
Using the dtwclust Package, pp.5-6

I don't understand what m_∅ is.
They say it is a per-step weighting coefficient. 
anybody help me??
just give me clue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is a phi $\phi$, not a diameter ∅.

The small $m_\phi$ are weight terms, $M_\phi = \sum_i m_\phi$ is the normalization term to make them sum to 1.

This way, you can have different weights.